# does not show data on second page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$_PHP_SELF = "tut.php";
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'sql';
$rec_limit = 2;
//$cat =$_POST['Mobiles'];
if(isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category']) {
  $cat= $_REQUEST['category'];

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('enquirytm');
/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM postad where scategory = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];
if( isset($_GET['page'] ) )
{
   $page = $_GET['page'] + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT * ".
       "FROM postad where scategory = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "'  ".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Title :{$row['id']}  <br> ".

         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 

if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?category='$cat' & page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?category='$cat' & page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?category='$cat' & page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?category='$cat' & page=$page\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

i tried lot of method bt all things are waste of my time..
can someone help in solve out this problem..
actually my problem is then i clicking on next page nothing happened..
please help me..
thanks in advance..

Comment: remove $_PHP_SELF = "tut.php"; and replace with some other variable like $url or something

Comment: tut.php is same file for pagination which would be reload..

Comment: i change it bt nothing happens..

Comment: $url=tut.php use in place of $_PHP_SELF = "tut.php"; replace all your $_PHP_SELF

Comment: yaa i do same thing.. bt nothing happens..